# Exception: No protocol while reading XML

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse xml data from string bufer or string ..i do code as follows.
here on the line `document doc =db.parse(eventXml )` ..it throws exception-- plesae find below code and exception .plese help me

**Code**

```
eventXml = strBuffer.toString();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse(eventXml );
```

**Exception**

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8
    " standalone="yes"?>%0A<EventInfo xmlns="http://www.telenet.be/oms/event">%0A
     <TelenetEventInfo className="be.telenet.oms.events.OmsAsapJsrpNotifyEvent">%0A
           <SimpleFields>%0A            <SimpleField>%0A                <FieldName>C
    ompletion_Date_Time</FieldName>%0A                <FieldValue>04/08/2009 08:34:0
    1</FieldValue>%0A            </SimpleField>%0A            <SimpleField>%0A
              <FieldName>Originator</FieldName>%0A                <FieldValue>System
    </FieldValue>%0A            </SimpleField>%0A            <SimpleField>%0A
             <FieldName>Status</FieldName>%0A                <FieldValue>S</FieldVal
    ue>%0A            </SimpleField>%0A            <SimpleField>%0A                <
    FieldName>Workorder_ID</FieldName>%0A                <FieldValue>I00054132231-09
    8</FieldValue>%0A            </SimpleField>%0A        </SimpleFields>%0A
    <ArrayData>%0A            <ArrayNames>%0A                <ArrayName>Parameters</
    ArrayName>%0A                <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubFi
    eld>[0].Parameter_Name</ArraySubField>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue
    >WARNING_TEXT</ArraySubFieldValue>%0A                </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A
              <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubField>[0].Parameter_v
    alue</ArraySubField>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue>UnknownKeyExcepti
    on-Retrieving a webURL%0A                    for an unknown loginid: a004301</Ar
    raySubFieldValue>%0A                </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                <ArrayF
    ieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubField>[1].Parameter_Name</ArraySubFiel
    d>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue>AGED</ArraySubFieldValue>%0A
             </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A
          <ArraySubField>[1].Parameter_value</ArraySubField>%0A                    <
    ArraySubFieldValue/>%0A                </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                <Arr
    ayFieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubField>[2].Parameter_Name</ArraySubF
    ield>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue>OPERATION</ArraySubFieldValue>%0
    A                </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A
                  <ArraySubField>[2].Parameter_value</ArraySubField>%0A
           <ArraySubFieldValue>DEL</ArraySubFieldValue>%0A                </ArrayFie
    ldEntry>%0A                <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubFiel
    d>[3].Parameter_Name</ArraySubField>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue>S
    USPEND</ArraySubFieldValue>%0A                </ArrayFieldEntry>%0A
       <ArrayFieldEntry>%0A                    <ArraySubField>[3].Parameter_value</A
    rraySubField>%0A                    <ArraySubFieldValue/>%0A                </Ar
    rayFieldEntry>%0A            </ArrayNames>%0A        </ArrayData>%0A        <eve
    ntName>OMS::ASAP::JSRP::Notify</eventName>%0A        <destination>OSB</destinati
    on>%0A    </TelenetEventInfo>%0A</EventInfo>%0A%0A
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:537)
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:434)
            at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:383)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityMan
    ager.java:836)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDocumentEntity(XMLE
    ntityManager.java:782)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setInputSource(XML
    DocumentScannerImpl.java:260)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(DTDConfiguratio
    n.java:499)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(DTDConfiguratio
    n.java:581)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:152)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
            at weblogic.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilder
    Impl.java:201)
            at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuild
    er.java:149)
            at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
            at Controller.getEvent_Xml(Controller.jpf:822)
            at Controller.GetDetails(Controller.jpf:487)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowCont
    roller.java:1512)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(Flow
    Controller.java:1447)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowControl
    ler.java:778)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlo
    wController.java:211)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java
    :608)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Reques
    tProcessor.java:484)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerf
    orm(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:1504)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.ja
    va:274)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowR
    equestProcessor.java:674)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegi
    sterActionServlet.java:527)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActi
    onServlet.java:152)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)

            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl$ServletInvocationAction.run
    (ServletStubImpl.java:1072)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubIm
    pl.java:465)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubIm
    pl.java:348)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
    n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:6985)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
    dSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
    121)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppSe
    rvletContext.java:3892)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestIm
    pl.java:2766)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
      Closing down all connections...

    <Jun 8, 2009 4:03:18 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext(id=312
    55131,name=ECToolWeb,context-path=/ECToolWeb)] Servlet failed with IOException
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.read(PostInputStream.java:1
    70)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStr
    eamImpl.java:180)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.mergePostParams(ServletR
    equestImpl.java:1339)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.parseQueryParams(Servlet
    RequestImpl.java:1206)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequ
    estImpl.java:1409)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequ
    estImpl.java:1395)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.scoping.ScopedServletUtils.getScopedSessio
    nAttrName(ScopedServletUtils.java:301)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.getCurrentActionResolver(Pag
    eFlowUtils.java:496)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.getCurrentPageFlow(PageFlowU
    tils.java:478)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.ensureCurrentPageFlow(PageFl
    owUtils.java:454)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowJspFilter.doFilter(PageFlowJspFilt
    er.java:193)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.ja
    va:27)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
    n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:6987)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
    dSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
    121)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppSe
    rvletContext.java:3892)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestIm
    pl.java:2766)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    --------------- nested within: ------------------
    weblogic.utils.NestedRuntimeException: Cannot parse POST parameters of request:
    '/ECToolWeb/DetailDisplay.jsp' - with nested exception:
    [java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.mergePostParams(ServletR
    equestImpl.java:1364)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.parseQueryParams(Servlet
    RequestImpl.java:1206)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequ
    estImpl.java:1409)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequ
    estImpl.java:1395)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.scoping.ScopedServletUtils.getScopedSessio
    nAttrName(ScopedServletUtils.java:301)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.getCurrentActionResolver(Pag
    eFlowUtils.java:496)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.getCurrentPageFlow(PageFlowU
    tils.java:478)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.ensureCurrentPageFlow(PageFl
    owUtils.java:454)
            at com.bea.wlw.netui.pageflow.PageFlowJspFilter.doFilter(PageFlowJspFilt
    er.java:193)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.ja
    va:27)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
    n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:6987)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
    dSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
    121)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppSe
    rvletContext.java:3892)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestIm
    pl.java:2766)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    >
.
```

Comment: jrharshath: Although I agree with you, your attitude does not belong here.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706493/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol

Answer (score 37):

You are invoking

```
Document doc = db.parse(eventXml);
```

with eventXml apparently being a string of XML data.

However, the method [DocumentBuilder.parse(String)](http://zx81/doku/java/javadoc/j2se1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)) expects a URI to *load* the XML from. That's why you get a MalformedURLException: Java tries to use your XML as an URI.

You want DocumentBuilder.parse(InputSource), or DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream). The InputStream can be created from your String/StringBuffer using e.g.

```
new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString))
```

(untested).

Comment: +1 Tested and it works. StringBufferInputStream is deprecated.

Answer (score 35):

`parse()` doesn't take actual XML as a parameter, instead it takes URL to a document.

You should use 
`DocumentBuilder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(eventXml));`

Comment: (+1) .. as clearly written in the JavaDoc for DocumentBuilder#parse. If still in doubt, google for 'DocumentBuilder' and follow the first link.

Comment: `StringBufferInputStream` is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html). There is a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1706533/1851290

Comment: You can use `new ByteArrayInputStream(eventXml.getBytes("utf-8"))` to replace the deprecated `StringBufferInputStream`

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `db.parse(eventXml)`, try:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(eventXml)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have posted so much content but nothing that can help any reader to see what you were trying to do.
If your problem is just that XML parsing is giving you a problem then check that your XML is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work.

```
private String updateMyXML(String orderXML) {
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(orderXML));
}
```