# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, xml, exception

I am getting Java exception like:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol
```

My program is trying to parse an XML string by using:

```
Document dom;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
dom = db.parse(xml);
```

The XML string contains:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
    "   <s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
    "       <s:Header>"+
    "           <ActivityId CorrelationId=\"15424263-3c01-4709-bec3-740d1ab15a38\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics\">50d69ff9-8cf3-4c20-afe5-63a9047348ad</ActivityId>"+
    "           <clalLog_CorrelationId xmlns=\"http://clalbit.co.il/clallog\">eb791540-ad6d-48a3-914d-d74f57d88179</clalLog_CorrelationId>"+
    "       </s:Header>"+
    "       <s:Body>"+
    "           <ValidatePwdAndIPResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"+
    "           <ValidatePwdAndIPResult xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClalBit.ClalnetMediator.Contracts\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
    "           <a:ErrorMessage>Valid User</a:ErrorMessage>"+
    "           <a:FullErrorMessage i:nil=\"true\" />"+
    "           <a:IsSuccess>true</a:IsSuccess>"+
    "           <a:SecurityToken>999993_310661843</a:SecurityToken>"+
    "           </ValidatePwdAndIPResult>"+
    "           </ValidatePwdAndIPResponse>"+
    "       </s:Body>\n"+
    "   </s:Envelope>\n";
```

Any suggestions about what is causing this error?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error message? While parsing the XML, or while trying to send it over the network? It would be really strange if you get this while parsing.

Comment: duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964311/exception-no-protocol-while-reading-xml/964377

Answer (score 448):

The documentation could help you : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html

The method `DocumentBuilder.parse(String)` takes a URI and tries to open it. If you want to directly give the content, you have to give it an `InputStream` or `Reader`, for example a `StringReader`. ... Welcome to the Java standard levels of indirections !

Basically :

```
DocumentBuilder db = ...;
String xml = ...;
db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Note that if you read your XML from a file, you can directly give the `File` object to `DocumentBuilder.parse()` .

As a side note, this is a pattern you will encounter a lot in Java. Usually, most API work with Streams more than with Strings. Using Streams means that potentially not all the content has to be loaded in memory at the same time, which can be a great idea !

Comment: @Guillaume, doing that I get document = null. Why does this happen?

Comment: No idea without looking at the code. Maybe your input is invalid and you swallow exception somehow ...

Comment: This line of code takes long time to execute. Any way to improve performance?

Comment: +1 for me assuming (foolishly, of course) that the string parameter was supposed to the xml to parse.... Of course, it makes _perfect_ sense to expect a URI instead....

Comment: @RajShah You should only run this logic at startup, so a larger time hit shouldnt matter. You shouldn't have to change the configuration very often, either....

Comment: The document printed out as `[#document: null]`, but `document.getDocumentElement()` returned the expected XML.

Comment: If I do that inputsource and stringbuilder, I get `:1:1: Premature end of file.`

Answer (score 29):

Try instead of `db.parse(xml)`:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(**xml**)));
```